# How to redirect 301 old url path to new url path

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

is there any way to redirect old post url to a new one?

The old one:

```
 https://www.example.com/programm/18-06-2018/episode/post-title-xyz
```

to the new one

```
 https://www.example.com/post-title-xyz
```

I have more then 20.000 of this type or url's and the date is always different.

Is it possible that the condition delete all between example.com and the post title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this single redirect rule for all the URLs that start with `/program/`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/program/.+/([^/]+)/?$ /$1
```